# how to load data to picker view inside custom tableview cell in ios, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uitableview

I have a table view and few custom cells.in one custom cell there is a picker view.I need to load the data to the picker view at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

this is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifierOne = @"detailCell";
    FlightUserTableViewCell *detailcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierOne];

    NSString *cellIdentifierTwo = @"detailCelltwo";
    FlightUserSecondTableViewCell *detailcelltwo = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierTwo];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        if (indexPath.row ==0) {

            //detailcell.titlepickerView **here i want to load the data **

            return detailcell;
        }
        return detailcelltwo;
    }



    return detailcelltwo;
}
```

how can I do that.I know if we load data to picker view normally we have to implement it's delegate methods like below.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [cabinArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [cabinArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

so how can I do that for the picker view inside the custom cell.hope your help.

as the answers, I have implemented `delegate` methods inside the custome tableview cell like this

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    return [leadandadultTitle count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [leadandadultTitle objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

then inside the `cellForRowAtIndexpath` I have implemented like this.

```
 if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        NSString *cellIdentifierOne = @"detailCell";
        FlightUserTableViewCell *detailcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierOne];

        if (indexPath.row ==0) {

            if([traveller isEqualToString:@"LEAD"])
            {

                detailcell.leadandadultTitle = leadandadultTitle;
                detailcell.titlepickerView.delegate = self;
                detailcell.titlepickerView.dataSource = self;
            }
            else
            {
               detailcell.leadandadultTitle = childandinfantTitle;
            }



            return detailcell;
        }
```

Note :I tried with setting the `delegate` and `datasource` like above and also tried dragging the pickerview and selecte `delegate` and `datasource` but

`numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` this gives

Comment: Implement the picker delegate protocol in your custom cell and set the data you want the picker to display on `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: you mean I have to implement the delegate methods inside my cutom cell class, and then how can I load the data at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the full answer for the to implement `pickerview` inside the `custom tableview cell`

in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, implement the normal way

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifierOne = @"detailCell";
    FlightUserTableViewCell *detailcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierOne];

    NSString *cellIdentifierTwo = @"detailCelltwo";
    FlightUserSecondTableViewCell *detailcelltwo = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierTwo];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        if (indexPath.row ==0) {

            detailcell.leadandadultTitle = leadandadultTitle;
            return detailcell;
        }

        detailcell.leadandadultTitle = otherTitle;
        return detailcelltwo;
    }



    return detailcelltwo;
}
```

then in your custom tableview cell class implement `pickerview` delegate methods like normal way

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    return [leadandadultTitle count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [leadandadultTitle objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

and the important part is, in your custom tableview cell class inside the following method do `delegate` and `datasource` like following.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
    self.titlepickerView.delegate = self;
    self.titlepickerView.dataSource = self;
}
```

so this solve the problem to me.special thanx to @Eric his answer helped me lot.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the picker delegate protocol in your custom cell and set the data you want the picker to display on `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSString *cellIdentifierOne = @"detailCell";
  FlightUserTableViewCell *detailcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierOne];

  NSString *cellIdentifierTwo = @"detailCelltwo";
  FlightUserSecondTableViewCell *detailcelltwo = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierTwo];

  if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    if (indexPath.row ==0) {
        detailCell.cabinArray = cabinArray
        return detailcell;
    }
    return detailcelltwo;
  }

  return detailcelltwo;
}
```

Comment: it gives this error :`numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: the `delegate` and `datasource` should be the `detailCell` not `self` but that part should be set in the custom cell itself

Comment: I dragged the pickerview and selected `delegate` and `datasource` then it gives this error

Comment: did you set the `detailCell` as `delegate` and `datasource`? Then you have not implemented `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` on the detailCell

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSString *cellIdentifierOne = @"detailCell";
  FlightUserTableViewCell *detailcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierOne];

  NSString *cellIdentifierTwo = @"detailCelltwo";
  FlightUserSecondTableViewCell *detailcelltwo = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierTwo];

  if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    if (indexPath.row ==0) {
       UIPickerView *pickerView=(UIPickerView *)[detailCell viewWithTag:12]; //  12 replace value by tag of your pickerView tag in cell 

        pickerView.delegate = self;
        pickerView.dataSource = self;
        return detailcell;
    }
    return detailcelltwo;
  }

  return detailcelltwo;
}
```